# How do I get the random numbers i called into an array?

Tags: java

Write a complete Java program that constructs a fictional gradebook and prints it to the command line. The gradebook data must be constructed as a multi-dimensional array with 10 rows. Each row has six elements: a student name in the first position, four assignment scores, and an assignment average in the last position. The assignment scores are produced (returned) by a second method that uses Math.random() and number scaling to produce a number between 0-100. The average is computed from the four assignment values. Your program should consist of at least three methods, each of which does a part of the work. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        gradebook();
    }
    public static void gradebook(){


        findingNumbers();
        final int NAMES = 6;
        final int ASSIGNMENTS = 4;
        String [] names ={"Mike", "Jayson", "Ben","Luke", "Chris", "Joseph"};




        System.out.println("Name      Assign 1    Assign 2    Assign 3   Assign 4    Average");
        for (int i = 0; i < NAMES; i++){
            System.out.printf("%10s", names[i]);
            double total = 0;
            double average = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < ASSIGNMENTS; j++){

                for(int k = 0; k < ASSIGNMENTS; k++){
                    int[] assingments = new int[4];
                    assingments[k] =(int) (Math.random()*100);
                }
                System.out.printf("%8d", assingments[i][j]);
                total = total + assingments[i][j];
                average = total/4;

            }
           System.out.printf("%2d", average);

        }

        }
    public static double findingNumbers(){
        double randomNumber = 0;
        randomNumber = Math.random();
        randomNumber = randomNumber *100;
               int randomInteger = 0;
               randomInteger = (int) randomNumber; 
        return randomInteger;
}



}
```

Comment: Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: this section of code :System.out.printf("%8d", assingments[i][j]);
                total = total + assingments[i][j];
                average = total/4;

Comment: What is your question? What seems to be a problem? Does your code compile? Does it run? Does it throws any exceptions and/or errors?

Comment: What about that section?

Comment: i get an error message at this code System.out.printf("%8d", assingments[i][j]);
                total = total + assingments[i][j];
                average = total/4;

Comment: First of all, you haven't declared a 2D array. Secondly, tell your teacher he's retarded for assigning an assignment like this where he's telling you to make a 2D matrix with `String` and `double`

Comment: yea thanks i know he is. okay so i declare a 2D array. but how do i get the random numbers into that array?

Answer (score 0):

A multi-dimensional array is an array with more than one dimension. You are creating an array with only one dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would have approached the problem:

```
public class ReportCard {

String[][] report = new String[11][6]; //first row contains column names

// constructor that initializes the first row
public ReportCard(){
    report[0][0] = "Name";
    report[0][1] = "Sub1";
    report[0][2] = "Sub2";
    report[0][3] = "Sub3";
    report[0][4] = "Sub4";
    report[0][5] = "Average";
}

// function to display report card
public void displayReportCard(){        
    for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
            System.out.print(report[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }       
}

// fill the marks with random numbers between 0 and 100
public void fillReportCard(){
    for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<6; j++){
            report[i][j] = String.valueOf(Math.floor(Math.random()*100)); 
        }
    }
}

//function to compute average of columns 1-4
public void getAverage(){
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<5; j++){
            sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(report[i][j]);               
        }
        report[i][5] = String.valueOf(sum/4);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    ReportCard r1 = new ReportCard();
    r1.fillReportCard();
    r1.getAverage();
    r1.displayReportCard();
}

}
```

Hope this helps :)